# Como se inserta la función reverse=True en sorted() be python

Tags: python-3.x

print(sorted()
Ahi como pongo Reverse=True

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, `reverse` es un argumento de `sorted`, no es la función `reversed` (fíjate que el nombre de la función `reversed` tiene una `d` al final).

Se puede decir que estas dos expresiones son equivalentes:

```py
lista_ordenada_inversa = reversed(sorted(lista))

lista_ordenada_inversa = sorted(lista, reverse=True)
```

Pero siempre será más efectiva la segunda, con `sorted` ordenando al revés, que encadenar dos operaciones. El argumento `reverse` sólo se puede pasar por nombre, tal como ves.

Comment: Gracias de verdad